# gls style latex

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I'm using glossary in latex and I wonder if or how can I change the style of the word-hyperlink to an entry which created via `\gls{glossary-item}`?
I've tried it via `\newenvironment{*style changes here*}`, but then the hyperlink to the glossary is missing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
\usepackage{ulem} % dotted underline 
(...)
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\dotuline{#1}}
```

[Source](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#x1-280006)